# :CSS keyframe elements animate only when visible in viewport?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

http://www.samnorris.co.nz

In the About section under 'Proficiencies' I have a "Skills Progression Bar" list made with CSS, which is supposed to animate using keyframes - but the animation cannot be seen on my page presumably because it is running as soon as the page loads.

Is there any way to delay or trigger the keyframe animations only when the 'Proficiencies' heading/slide is clicked, or alternatively only when the container with the skills bar is visible in the viewport?

I am aware of the various techniques to only run an animation when the page is scrolled to a certain point, but in this instance obviously that's not quite what I want...

Relevant code (for Krish):

CSS

```
.about-skills {
    width:398px;
    margin:0;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    font-size:12px;
    line-height:2em;
    padding:30px 0 30px;
    margin-left: 15px;
}

.skills-col { width:400px; }

.skills-list { 
    display: none;
    list-style:none; 
    padding-top:20px;
}

.skills-list li { 
    margin-bottom:50px; 
    background:#ececec; 
    height:5px; 
    border-radius:3px; 
    border-left:1px solid #cecece; 
    border-top:1px solid #cecece; 
    border-right:1px solid #cecece; 
    border-bottom:1px solid #b5b5b5;  
}

.skills-list li em { 
    position:relative; 
    top:-30px;
}

.skills-expand {
    height:1px; 
    margin:2px 0; 
    background:#0dc9ff; 
    position:absolute;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 10px 1px rgba(0,198,255,0.4);
}

.html5       { display: block; width:85%;  -moz-animation:html5 2s ease-out;       -webkit-animation:html5 2s ease-out;       }
.css3        { display: block; width:70%;  -moz-animation:css3 2s ease-out;        -webkit-animation:css3 2s ease-out;        }
.jquery      { display: block; width:50%;  -moz-animation:jquery 2s ease-out;      -webkit-animation:jquery 2s ease-out;      }
.php         { display: block; width:20%;  -moz-animation:php 2s ease-out;   -webkit-animation:php 2s ease-out;   }
.dreamweaver { display: block; width:100%; -moz-animation:dreamweaver 2s ease-out; -webkit-animation:dreamweaver 2s ease-out; }
.photoshop   { display: block; width:100%; -moz-animation:photoshop 2s ease-out;   -webkit-animation:photoshop 2s ease-out; }
.responsive  { display: block; width:40%; -moz-animation:responsive 2s ease-out;   -webkit-animation:responsive 2s ease-out; }

@-moz-keyframes html5       { 0%  { width:0px;} 100%{ width:85%;}  }
@-moz-keyframes css3        { 0%  { width:0px;} 100%{ width:70%;}  }
@-moz-keyframes jquery      { 0%  { width:0px;} 100%{ width:50%;}  }
@-moz-keyframes php         { 0%  { width:0px;} 100%{ width:20%;}  }
@-moz-keyframes photoshop   { 0%  { width:0px;} 100%{ width:100%;} }
@-moz-keyframes dreamweaver { 0%  { width:0px;} 100%{ width:100%;} }
@-moz-keyframes responsive  { 0%  { width:0px;} 100%{ width:40%;} }

@-webkit-keyframes html5       { 0%  { width:0px;} 100%{ width:85%;}  }
@-webkit-keyframes css3        { 0%  { width:0px;} 100%{ width:70%;}  }
@-webkit-keyframes jquery      { 0%  { width:0px;} 100%{ width:50%;}  }
@-webkit-keyframes php         { 0%  { width:0px;} 100%{ width:20%;}  }
@-webkit-keyframes photoshop   { 0%  { width:0px;} 100%{ width:100%;} }
@-webkit-keyframes dreamweaver { 0%  { width:0px;} 100%{ width:100%;} }
@-webkit-keyframes responsive  { 0%  { width:0px;} 100%{ width:40%;} }
```

jQuery

```
$('a.proficiencies').click(function(){
  $('.skills-list').toggleClass('html5');
});
```

Comment: Add a class using javascript when the element becomes visible. You do want the animation to run when it's scrolled to a certain point - when the section is reached. There are many SO questions on this. Also please include the *relevant* code inside of the question itself because the problem will no longer show once the problem is fixed

Comment: this is what you want http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pygqJ

Comment: Hey, I followed your example - and it seems like it's doing something, but it's kinda screwed up - could you please take a look at the example here: http://www.samnorris.co.nz/test/  and see what I might have done wrong? have also updated my post with relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

after look at your code it will work good with the jquery `addClass` on the click of `a` link

**HTML Structure**

```
    <a class="proficiencies">Proficiencies(click)</a>
    <ul>
      <li><em>HTML5</em><span class="skills-expand html5anim"></span></li>
      <li><em>CSS3</em><span class="skills-expand css3anim"></span></li>
    </ul>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('a.proficiencies').click(function(){
  $('.html5anim').addClass('html5');

  $('.css3anim').addClass('css3');
});
```

Live Demo : http://codepen.io/krish4u/pen/fyehA

Comment: @FuManchuNZ I don't know more than this.